# The basic mapping 'subject.errCode' cannot be used in conjunction with the = operator

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I am migrating hibernate to spring data jpa, it gives error for namedquery

```
    {@NamedQuery(name = "student.HSLoad", query = " FROM Student student WHERE CAST(SUBSTRING(student.nameId,2,12) AS long) >CAST( :value1 AS long) AND CAST(SUBSTRING(student.nameId,2,12) AS long)<= CAST( :value2  AS long) AND student.nameId is not null and not exists(select distinct nameId from Subject subject where student.nameId=subject.nameId  and  not exists(SELECT secondary FROM ListLibrary listLibrary WHERE  primary='Mem Conversion Errors' and text like '%;W' and secondary = subject.errCode ))")}

as
[363, 384] The basic mapping 'subject.errCode' cannot be used in conjunction with the = operator.
[135, 141] The identification variable 'nameId' is not defined in the FROM clause.
[248, 257] The identification variable 'secondary' is not defined in the FROM clause.
[293, 300] The identification variable 'primary' is not defined in the FROM clause.
[331, 335] The identification variable 'text' is not defined in the FROM clause.
[351, 360] The identification variable 'secondary' is not defined in the FROM clause.
[135, 141] The identification variable 'nameId' is not defined in the FROM clause.
```

Comment: apparently this `secondary = subject.errCode` is wrong. can u remove it, and run it again?

Comment: anyway, do u have a `select`?

Comment: Thank you ,bt {secondary = subject.errCode} was in hql just am migrating to jpa

Comment: is it necessary in jpa query?(select)

Comment: add the ListLibrary  and Subject entity mapping classes

Comment: is it compulsory to give alise name for inner query in jpql? bcos, after giving alise for secondary in **secondary = subject.errCode** work for me..thank you :)